# Api returning email is not valid in android testing, but works on Postman

Tags: android, http, retrofit2, crud

I have an Api for registering user to Database. I am using Retrofit2 library for consuming the Api.

The register api when I test it on postman returns perfect result but when I implement it in my android app, it give the error that email is not valid.

I have used all kind of email validations so that form is only submitted when email is valid. I can't understand the issue with this.

Here is my api for your reference:

```
**http://ec2-54-201-213-169.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:9000/api/v1/auth/signup**
```

Here is my **Retrofit Api**:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("auth/signup")
    Call<DefaultResponse> signup(
            @Field("userId") String userId,
            @Field("email") String email,
            @Field("firstName") String firstName,
            @Field("lastName") String lastName,
            @Field("password") String password,
            @Field("confirmPassword") String confirmPassword

    );
```

Api has a built in check for validating email, It get triggered when I run my app even though email is Valid.

Here is the **Java Implementation**:

```
 Call<DefaultResponse> call = RetrofitClient
                .getInstance()
                .getApi()
                .signup(firstName, lastName, email, password, confirmPassword, userId);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<DefaultResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<DefaultResponse> call, Response<DefaultResponse> response) {

                DefaultResponse defaultResponse = response.body();
                if (response.code() == 200) {
                    ViewUtils.showSuccessToast(RegisterActivity2.this, "Registered Successful");
                } else if (response.code() == 201) {
                    ViewUtils.showErrorToast(RegisterActivity2.this, defaultResponse.getMsg());
                }

                loader.hide();
                register_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<DefaultResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                showErrorToast(RegisterActivity2.this, t.getMessage());
                loader.hide();
                register_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

My default response model:

```
public class DefaultResponse {
    @SerializedName("error")
    private boolean err;

    @SerializedName("message")
    private String msg;

    public DefaultResponse(boolean err, String msg) {
        this.err = err;
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public boolean isErr() {
        return err;
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here Api end point

```
signup(
            @Field("userId") String userId,
            @Field("email") String email,
            @Field("firstName") String firstName,
            @Field("lastName") String lastName,
            @Field("password") String password,
            @Field("confirmPassword") String confirmPassword

    );
```

incorrect order of data passing. API end point expect second param as email but you are passing lastname

```
.signup(firstName, lastName, email, password, confirmPassword, userId);
```

try with correct order.